# Troca de letras em uma palavra

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer um código que substitua as letras de uma palavra, como a letra A por @, tentei esse código porem ele troca apenas uma letra, se tentar colocar mais ele dá erro, como faço?

Código:

```
trocar = input('Qual seu nome?')
def troca(quero_trocar, trocar_por, frase):
    return frase.replace(quero_trocar, trocar_por)

print(troca('a', '@', trocar)) #M@ri@
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o método [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) que retorna uma cópia da string na qual cada caractere foi mapeado através da tabela de tradução que pode ser obtida com o auxilio do método estático [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) que pode ser invocado com dois argumentos to tipo string de mesmo tamanho onde será criada uma tabela de correspondências os caracteres da primeira string serão transformados pelos respectivos caracteres na segunda string:

```python
trocar = input('Qual seu nome?') #Maria
def troca(quero_trocar, trocar_por, frase):
    tbl = str.maketrans(quero_trocar, trocar_por)
    return frase.translate(tbl)

print(troca('aM', '@W', trocar)) #W@ri@
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Replit](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Transliterar#main.py)</sup>